# I have two UK passports. Do US CBP know of both passports or just one i show?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, sudan

I have two UK passports. On one i have a valid ESTA, on the other i have recently travelled to Sudan. Will US CBP know details of travel in both passports? I ask this as from 21/01/16 an ESTA is no longer valid for people to have been to Sudan since 2011.

Comment: It's worth noting that you are no longer eligable for the VWP - it's whether you have visited the countries on the list, not your passport. Of course,a s the related question shows, its another question if they know about it. As a UK citizen though you're about the least likley to get away with it (given the amount of information sharing between the US and the UK)

Comment: @CMaster Why would UK authorities be aware of the visit to Sudan? Even if passports contain some high-tech magic, it's not like that they are automatically transmitting stamps put into them by foreign immigration officers to the issuing country.

Comment: Well there are lots of ways that the UK government could know - especially if you took a flight from the UK to Sudan. If there is any attempt made at logging the travels of UK citizens made though, I have no idea.

Comment: It boggles my mind that you would even be considering doing this. America is not known (and I am a citizen and resident as well) for 'taking it easy' on people it thinks may have suspected "ties to terrorism"... Yes, you could probably get away with it, but what do you do if/when the US Government finds out you intentionally broke the rules? At the _least_ they'll likely deport/ban you, the _worst_? Try sending a letter to an inmate at GITMO?  What inmates in GITMO, you ask? Exactly.

Comment: @CMaster it's also worth noting that the ESTA is not "valid" from a legal point of view, even if it hasn't been cancelled in the database.  Reggie: your chances of getting away with it might be good, but you have no way of knowing, really, what they are.  The consequences for being caught are severe, and the cost of playing it safe is $160 for a visa application plus incidental expenses and a trip to a US consulate or embassy.  Assuming your trip to Sudan was legitimate in the eyes of the US and you can show it, it may be a small price to pay to avoid the risk of being banned from the US.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My trip to Sudan was for legitimate business that I can evidence so I think I will now apply for a visa.